# column drilldown like highcharts in dc.js charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js

I'm building a multi-drilldown using dc js charts. I want to also be able to use a beautiful highcharts functionality as shown [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown)

I have a pie chart and a couple of bar, line charts connected to the pie chart.

Is there a way to convert bar chart to open up like a column drill-down feature as shown in highcharts?

Any approach/suggestions would be highly appreciated.

My code so far for pie chart and bar chart are as follows :

```
var chart = dc.pieChart("#test");
var chart2 = dc.barChart("#test2");

d3.csv("dataset_2.csv", function(error, experiments) {

  console.log(experiments[0]);
  //Filtering only target population
  experiments = experiments.filter(function (d) { return d.target_ind == "1"; });

  var ndx  = crossfilter(experiments);
  var all = ndx.groupAll();

  bucketDimension  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return "Bucket : " +d.decay_bucket;});
  speedSumGroup = bucketDimension.group().reduceSum( function(d) { return d.Count ;});
dateDimension  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.rate_plan ;});
  rechGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum ( function(d) { return d.recharge_revenue ;});

 //Pie chart declarations
chart
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    //.slicesCap(6)
    .innerRadius(100)
    .dimension(bucketDimension)
    .group(speedSumGroup)
    .legend(dc.legend());


//Bar chart declarations

chart2
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    //.brushOn(false)
    .yAxisLabel("Recharge Revenue")
    .dimension(dateDimension)
    .group(rechGroup)
    .on('renderlet', function(chart) {
        chart.selectAll('rect').on("click", function(d) {
            console.log("click!", d);
        });
    });


dc.renderAll();

dc.redrawAll();
});
```

How do I go about opening up a bar chart as that of column drill-down? Assuming the time dimensions are month-week mapping or alike etc?

Comment: I think it will probably be easier to send your data from dc.js to highcharts, as long as you don't need to filter the other charts from the bar chart. That said, there is probably a way to do this using a custom click event handler.

Comment: @Gordon : Please answer this when your free, will be great help!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188115/dc-and-crossfilter-calculating-percentage-within-records