# dc and crossfilter - calculating percentage within records

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to calculate and plot percentage (%) in one of my dc charts.

I have read the API and multiple examples regarding reduce functions (add, remove & init etc)
I referred to [1st](http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/vct0dzou/8/) & [2nd](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/21) for my codes.

I want to calculate decay percentage ( sum(decay_data)/sum(all_data) ; decay_data is defined in data by "decay_ind==1" )

I'm still not getting anything in the graph due to some issue, the value accessor is also used but, there could be some issue in that.

In the code, please just see "percentgroup" and "datedimension" only, others are for separate charts.

My code so far :

```
 var chart = dc.pieChart("#test");
var chart2 = dc.barChart("#test2");
var chart3 = dc.barChart("#test3");

  console.log(data[0]);
  //Filtering only target population
  data = data.filter(function (d) { return d.target_ind == "1"; });

  var ndx  = crossfilter(data);


  bucketDimension  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return "Bucket : " +d.decay_bucket;});
  speedSumGroup = bucketDimension.group().reduceSum( function(d) { return d.Count ;});

  dateDimension  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.duration ;});
  rechGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum ( function(d) { return d.recharge_revenue ;});

    var percentGroup = dateDimension.group().reduce(
        //add
        function(p, v) {
            ++p.count;
            p.decay += (v.decay_ind === '1' ? p.recharge_revenue : 0);
            p.total += p.recharge_revenue;
            p.percent = p.count ? p.decay/p.total : 0;
            return p;
        },
        function(p, v) {
            --p.count;
            p.decay -= (v.decay_ind === '1' ? p.recharge_revenue : 0);
            p.total -= p.recharge_revenue;
            p.percent = p.count ? p.decay/p.total : 0;
            return p;
        },
        function() {
            return {
                count: 0,
                decay : 0,
                total : 0,
                percent : 0

            };
        }
        );


        chart3
        .width(768)
        .height(480)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        //.brushOn(false)
        .yAxisLabel("Decay %")
        .dimension(dateDimension)
        //.group(decayGroup)

        .on('renderlet', function(chart) {
            chart.selectAll('rect').on("click", function(d) {
                console.log("click!", d);
            });
        });


      chart3.valueAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.value.percent;
        })
        .group(percentGroup);
```

what am I missing here? 
Any approach/suggestions would be very helpful.

**UPDATE**

Okay, I've corrected a few mistakes and now, just trying to get the sum to understand these functions better and see them in the console. Added all values in duration dimension also.

I'm summing up a variable called "Recharge revenue", in the console - add function gives me, random/junk values. Remove function gives me infinity.

My new code :

```
var percentGroup = dateDimension.group().reduce(
    //add
    function(p, v) {
        ++p.count;
        p.total += v.recharge_revenue;
        //p.percent = p.count ? p.decay/p.total : 0;
        console.log(p.total);
        return p;
    },
    //remove
    function(p, v) {
        --p.count;
        p.total -= v.recharge_revenue;
        return p;
    },
    //init
    function() {
        return {
            count: 0,
            total : 0,

        };
    }
    );

chart3
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    //.brushOn(false)
    .yAxisLabel("Decay %")
    .dimension(dateDimension)
    .valueAccessor(function (p) {
    return p.value.total;
     })
    .group(percentGroup)
    .on('renderlet', function(chart) {
        chart.selectAll('rect').on("click", function(d) {
            console.log("click!", d);
        });
    });
```

The graph is still empty for obvious reasons (console displays)

Please help me fix this, I just can't get what's wrong here. Once sum is done, I want to go about calculating percentage.

Another caveat : I have a column "Count" in my dataset (csv), is that causing the problem here by any chance? (changed to another name, still not working)

Basically, the only thing working is *count* in graphs, if I use any sum, average, I'm getting random values and no graph plot.

Any suggestions/feedback will be most welcome.

**UPDATE 2 :**

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vct0dzou/23/)

Dataset has two buckets and two durations

It's showing junk/random values for both total and average. Please help me fix the issue now.

Comment: What values are you getting? Either set a breakpoint/log in the reduce function, or trace `percentGroup.all()` where the chart is initialized.

Comment: I'd suspect an issue with data and equality comparisons or well-ordered-ness. Is your decay indicator a string? If it's a number, it will never === '1'. Does duration always have a value? If not, your date dimension will not be well-ordered. I'd also recommend doing your actual % calculation in the value accessor. No need to run that calculation every time the reducer is called.

Comment: @G : The graph is empty, there are no values. (can only see x, y axis)
@EthanJewett : You are right, duration does not have a value everywhere, as I was just testing. Yes, decay indicator was imported as a string, tested both '1' and 1, neither are working. Can you share an example how to calculate inside value accessor, as I tried that,but not working again

Comment: The calculation inside the accessor isn't the problem, it was just a suggestion. The lack of duration values might be the problem. You should test for missing values in your accessor. Please put together a working example of this issue you are seeing (use JSfiddle or something similar) and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: @EthanJewett : Here's the fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/vct0dzou/23/ 

I have added my code and the dataset type, it's giving random/junk values, for both total and average, and it's drawing the pie chart here as it's small number of values. Can you please help fix the issue now?

Comment: @Gordon : Please help whenever your free, need to get this fixed. Lots of coding dependent on this

Comment: I got the answer, I was missing a simple "parseInt" in my values

Comment: Yeah that's why I suggested looking at the data in the debugger. Debugging blind is no fun! Glad you found it.

Comment: Glad you found it, and I agree with @Gordon of course :-) The example is a much faster way to get help, in general. Very few answerers can invest the time to convert code snippets into a working example, which is necessary to debug and determine where the problem is.

Comment: Agreed! Making the example only led me to the answer, will always make examples before posting questions now. Great learning, thanks a lot guys! Thank you for taking your time out to help us folks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers are in string format, had to be parsed into integer for the functions to read them, the values were junk as it was concatenating them.

**Solution code :**

```
function(p, v) {
        ++p.count;
        p.total += parseInt(v.recharge_revenue);
        //p.percent = p.count ? p.decay/p.total : 0;
        console.log(p.total);
        return p;
    },
    //remove
    function(p, v) {
        --p.count;
        p.total -= parseInt(v.recharge_revenue);
        return p;
    }
```